# How to remove existing item from array

Tags: list, flutter, setstate

i have four buttons in my app.Something like this

```
List<String> players = [
{'name': 'player 1'},
{'name': 'player 2'},
{'name': 'player 3'},
{'name': 'player 4'}
];
```

I'm iterating over a map

```
return Row(
        children: players
            .map((player) => RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () {selectPlayer(player)}
                  child: Text(player['name']),
                ))
            .toList());
```

my initial state looks like this:

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _selectedPlayers = [];
  }
```

`selectPlayer()` looks like this:

```
  selectPlayer(player) {
    if (_selectedPlayers.contains(player)) {
      _selectedPlayers.remove(player);
    } else {
      _selectedPlayers.add(player);
    }

    List newSelectedPlayers = _selectedPlayers;
    setState(() {
      _selectedPlayers = newSelectedPlayers;
    });
  }
```

If i remove `setState` in `selectPlayer`, and `print(newSelectedPlayers)`,

it all works accordingly. But i need to know if player has been added/removed, and therefore that's why i update state.

If, i do `setState`, then, in `build`, i try to log `_selectedPlayers`, they just get added, never removed, even though they shouldn't... or i'm missing something...

Thanks!

Comment: Remove this ```List<String> players = ['player 1', 'player 2', 'player 3', 'player 4'];``` from inside the build context put it right under your class name;

Comment: hey @ikben, thank you so much. This worked. I guess it's because flutter compares some internal indexes from list and therefore that's why setState didn't compare them good? Could you tell me more about this, please? Thanks!

Comment: really glad, I was able to help

Comment: Another thing you should know is that each time you set state, your app reload everything inside  ```@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)``` 

So when you want to declare a variable do it outside the build context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this `List<String> players = ['player 1', 'player 2', 'player 3', 'player 4'];` from inside the build context put it right under your class name;

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need the second newselectedplayers variable instead just do this inside your selectplayer funtion

```dart
setstate(() {
  if (_selectedPlayers.contains(player)) {
    _selectedPlayers.remove(player);
  } else {
    _selectedPlayers.add(player);
  }
});
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your time. sadly this doesn't fix my issue.